# Asp.Net core: call a custom method after response is returned from another middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to the asynchronous pattern in C# and trying to play with Asp.Net core.

I want to call the method InformUI() after the response is received from controller action in Middleware_NotifyWPF. 
How to do that? 
[Something like request.on('end') event handler for the Middleware_NotifyWPF.]

**Startup.cs :**

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.Middleware_NotifyWPF();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**Middleware 1:**

```
    public class Middleware_NotifyWPF
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
            private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            public Middleware_NotifyWPF(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                _next = next;
            }

            public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
            {
                return _next(httpContext);


                InformUI(httpContext.Request, httpContext.Response); //Unreachable code
            }
}
```

**Controller Class | Action Method**

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

Comment: Of course code is unreachable after a return statement, what where you expecting? Change the method to `async Task`, use `await _next(httpContext)` and remove that `return` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to await the Task in order to be able to reach the code after

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    await _next(httpContext);

    InformUI(httpContext.Request, httpContext.Response); 
}
```